# Make CSS code more clearly (delete repeated line)

Tags: html, css

How can I make this code more clearly. I mean remove this repeated part from the beginning. I think I should add to HTML and CSS `<li>` but and when I pasted it into this tag my `<span>` doesn't work at all...

CSS:

```
.box i.popular {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    background: url('../images/popular.png') no-repeat
}

.box i.upload {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    background: url('../images/upload.png') no-repeat;
}

.box i.diary {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    background: url('../images/diary.png') no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <a href="#"><div id="test"><div class="box"><p><i class="popular"></i><span>Inspiration</span></p></div></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div id="test"><div class="box"><p><i class="upload"></i><span>Upload photo</span></p></div></div></a>
    <a href="#"><div id="test"><div class="box"><p><i class="diary"></i><span>Go to diary</span></p></div></div></a>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Justinas : Learn pure CSS

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

You don't need to repeat your global box styles as they are all using the size and positional properties. So therefore attach the common styles to `.box` and the only thing you need to setup next is individual styles for the variants.

```
.box i{
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}
.box i.popular {
    background: url('../images/popular.png') no-repeat
}

.box i.upload {
    background: url('../images/upload.png') no-repeat;
}

.box i.diary {
    background: url('../images/diary.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: This is working perfect :) Sorry for that question because the solution is soooo simple... Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1):

boyd's answer is great, but sometimes you don't want to apply a style to all elements (in your case all `.box i` elements).

In that case you can use multiple CSS selectors with one style definition by separating them with commas:

```
/* This will apply to all listed selectors */

.box i.popular,
.box i.upload,
.box i.diary {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}

/* This adds some extra styles to each one at a time */

.box i.popular {
    background: url('../images/popular.png') no-repeat
}

.box i.upload {
    background: url('../images/upload.png') no-repeat;
}

.box i.diary {
    background: url('../images/diary.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Alternatively, you could also give them all a common class. This is how [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) works.

HTML:

```
... <i class="icon diary"></i> ...
```

CSS:

```
box i.icon {
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 1px;
}

.box i.popular {
    background: url('../images/popular.png') no-repeat
}

.box i.upload {
    background: url('../images/upload.png') no-repeat;
}

.box i.diary {
    background: url('../images/diary.png') no-repeat;
}
```